# Subdomain redirect language page

Tags: php, html

I have a quick question. Following problem I have a button on my website that automatically redirects to the German subdomain of the website.

```
<a href="https://german.hello.com"><img src="images/DE.png">German</a>
```

An example :

Mainpage: hello.com

Subdomain in the language german: german.hello.com

Now I have all subpages of both languages named exactly the same example :

Mainpage Imprint : hello.com/imprint
Subdomain in the language german : german.hello.com/imprint

How can I use a html button to redirect the person to the requested page of the language e.g. he is currently on the contact page how can he only get to german.hello.com/contact through a button ?

My idea the website needs to know where the user is and puts the subdomain german in front of the main domain so he gets the subpage of the selected language.

For this the website needs to know which subpage the user is currently on. In other words, the website must know the URL and simply add the subpage title like contact after the domain german.hello.com/contact. Therefore this must be a variable button.

I was thinking of something like :

```
<a href="https://german.hello.com{currentpage.php}"><img src="images/DE.png">German</a>
```

Comment: How do you construct the link to "contact"? Using `<a href="/contact">` should get the user to `hello.com/contact` if they are on hello.com and to `german.hello.com/contact` if they are on german.hello.com

Comment: @kerbholz the problem i only have one button this button should know the currentpage and redirect the user to the translated website of the subdomain

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **relative URLs**.

For example, if you are on page `hello.com/imprint` and want to come back on the *home* page, you may want to click on a button with href equals to `..`:

```
<a href="..">Home</a>
```

Vice versa, if you are on the home page and want to go on *imprint* page, you may want to click on a button with href equals to `imprint`:

```
<a href="/imprint">Imprint</a>
```

Note that with **relative URLS** you don't care in which subdomain you are: once you are in a specific subdomain, the **relative URLS** are completed by the browser with the correct one.

Comment: Can this also be done with window.location.href google.com{page.html}

Comment: Yes... Using same examples:
    window.location.href = '../';
or
    window.location.href = '/imprint';

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the user to the same page under a different subdomain, you can do something like:

```
<?php
$currentPage = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$link = "<a href='http://german.hello.com/$currentPage' ><img src='images/DE.png'>German </a>"; 

?>
```

Comment: Thank you :) But how exactly that should work should i paste something into Script_Name because that don't function

Comment: $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME] is a server variable that holds the value of the current php file that is being executed.. If you use all your links as relative links, when the user clicks on the link it will stay under the same subdomain.domain.com. The example that I posted was to change between subdomains and target the same file over another subdomain.